# Core Data fetch request predicate filtering across one-to-one relationship

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I have the following model graph:

```
                  +-----------+     +-----------+
                  | Container |     |   Group   |
                  +-----------+     +-----------+
                  |  groups   |<-->>| container |
                  +-----------+     +-----------+
                        ^                 ^
                        |                 |
+-----------+     +-----------+     +-----------+     +---------+
|   Owner   |     |  ToyBox   |     |  ToyType  |     |  Item   |
+-----------+     +-----------+     +-----------+     +---------+
|  toyBox   |<--->|   owner   |     |   items   |<-->>| toyType |
+-----------+     +-----------+     +-----------+     +---------+
```

In a UITableView I am to display a list a list of Items. In this case I only want to show the items that belong to a particular owner. To do this I will use NSFetchedResultsController to display the items. This means that I need create an NSFetchRequest with an appropriate NSPredicate to give to the NSFetchedResultsController.

Attempting to use a keypath predicate causes an exception due to the parent entities. This appears to be an Apple bug or decision not to support. A radar has been filed. Additionally, I do not wish to flatten the entities.

So that left me with an attempt to do this with SUBQUERY() as follows:

```
NSFetchRequest *itemsFetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Item"];
NSPredicate *itemsPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(toyItem, $g, SUBQUERY($g.container, $c, SUBQUERY($c.owner, $o, $o = %@).@count > 0).@count > 0).@count > 0", ownerObject];
```

This results in the following exception:

```
Can't have a non-relationship collection element in a subquerySUBQUERY($c.owner, $o, $o == <MLMOOwner: ...
```

I realize that because the relationship is one to one between Owner and ToyBox that there isn't a collection returned and this is the problem. So my questions are:

1) Is there a way to force the return of a collection for to-one relationships in the subquery?
2) If not is there another way to go about creating this predicate for the fetch request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like it should be a lot simpler to do what you want. If you want all the items with a given owner, start with the owner and use a key path to get the associated items. You don't need a predicate. If you've got 10 jars of peanuts and you want to retrieve the peanuts in jar 2, you don't start with the set of all peanuts and then filter them according to their jar, right? You first get jar 2, and then you look at the peanuts it contains. So do this:

```
NSSet *groups = [ownerObject valueForKeyPath:@"toyBox.groups"];
```

That gives you all the groups owned by `ownerObject`. You can't just get all the items using a single key path because the `Group` entity doesn't have an `items` attribute. You could make life easier for yourself by giving `Group` an `items` accessor, even if it only returns an empty set. That would let you do this:

```
NSSet *items = [ownerObject valueForKeyPath:@"toyBox.groups.items"];
```

If you don't want to add an `items` attribute to `Group`, you'll have to filter the set `groups` from the first example to pick out just those objects that are ToyType objects. You can then use the key path `@"items"` on that set to get the list of items that you want.

You have to be a bit careful with entity inheritance. You've just seen how it can make fetching a little more complicated. It also has implications for the way your data is stored, namely that [all instances of sub-entities are stored in the same table](http://chanson.livejournal.com/149812.html). So, if you have a dozen entities derived from `Group` (such as `ToyType`), all the instances of all those entities are stored together.

Comment: You could even leave the SELF. out.

Comment: @Caleb Thanks for the feedback. The first thing I implemented was a keypath approach and I get an exception there as well. I just tried it again and the following comes back: `keypath group.container.owner not found in entity <NSSQLEntity Item id=1>`

Comment: Sounds like there's a problem with your model, then, or with the code you used. Should work fine.

Comment: @Caleb I should have given all the information from the beginning. I have updated the question to more completely reflect the data model being use. In this case there are parent entities and the exception given above occurs when using a keypath and the model graph that I have updated. This is either an Apple bug or decision to not implement due to the possible edge cases. I have filed a bug but would like to move forward and would like to do so without flattening the entities if possible.

Comment: It's a little harder to follow your question now -- it's not entirely clear what you're trying to get. It looks to me like the exception you get if you use a keypath like the one I gave is due to the fact that the entity `Container` doesn't have an `owner` relationship. So a solution could be to use a keypath starting from `Item` like: `toyType.container` to get the container object. Then check that it's a ToyBox and get its `owner`. And yes, please don't leave out important info when asking.

Comment: @Caleb I hadn't thought to use the toyBox relationship of Owner. This does appear to work. Luckily this is an option for me since this relationship is strictly one-to-one. Please do modify your answer to reflect the slightly changed question with this newly proposed solution so I can accept it. Sorry for the changing of the question. I tried to make the question as straight forward the first time. I truly didn't believe the parent entities were part of the problem. However, thanks for hanging in there and helping!

Comment: @Caleb Yes, entity inheritance can be messy in Core Data. In this case I wanted to move certain very tedious functionality to the parent `Container` so that it can be unit tested separately. A side effect was that the code becomes reusable when needed in the future. Thanks again!

Comment: @MichaelLedford If you're using custom classes to implement your entities, those classes can have an inheritance relationship even if the entities themselves don't. Just something to consider.